# Embedded UICollectionView can't be accessed from main UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I embedded a UICollection View inside my main view, and I'm trying to feed it data already downloaded and put into arrays. However, the CollectionView delegates, which is defined on a separate class from the main VC,  doesn't seem to be running. Can't somebody point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class DiarioCollectionView: UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if defaults.boolForKey("gotPL") {
        print(defaults.arrayForKey("playlistTitles")!.count) //This is not being called..
        return defaults.arrayForKey("playlistTitles")!.count
    }
    print("No Data") //This is also not being called..
    return 0
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    print(indexPath)
    print(indexPath.item)
    print(indexPath.row)
    if defaults.boolForKey("gotPL") {
        let thumbIV = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
        let playTitle = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel

        thumbIV.image = UIImage(data: defaults.arrayForKey("playlistThumbnails")![indexPath.row] as! NSData)
        playTitle.text = defaults.arrayForKey("playlistTitles")![indexPath.row] as? String
        return cell
    }

    return cell
}
```

}

[image: UICollectionView defined as an instance of class DiarioCollectionView, inside my main ViewController]

(UICollectionView defined as an instance of class DiarioCollectionView, inside my main ViewController)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you load your data?
The collection view's delegate should be your main view.
If your mainView you are referring to is a viewcontroller, then it should implement both the dataSource and delegate protocol.

Also you need to set your collectionView's delgates (both UICollectionViewDelegate and UICollectionViewDataSource protocol)

You can either set these two delegates in storyboard or by code:

```
self.YOURCOLLECTIONVIEW.dataSource = self
self.YOURCOLLECTIONVIEW.delegate = self
```

Comment: BabyShung is right, your view controller should be the delegate, not the collection view itself.